# segregation of phases in a closed vertical well

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A droplet of water is falling down in a stationary gaseous phase in a vertical well. Suppose that the shape of my droplet is consistent, and there is no possibility of it absorbing or evaporating from the ambient gaseous phase. I want to find the equation of falling the droplet versus time, the velocity of up-warding bubble and the velocity of down-warding droplet. Also, whats your idea about the phenomena that are happening in the well an the effect of it on the pressure at bottom of the well?

Comment: What is the *up-warding bubble*? Also what do you mean by the pressure at the bottom of the well? Are you thinking that the increased air density with depth will slow the falling drop?

Comment: the bubbles tend to move  to the above of the well due to differences in liquid and gas densities,  I wanna calculate changes of pressure at the middle of the well

Comment: I assume that gas and oil densities are constant with time and depth

Comment: This is basically flow past a sphere.  Use the relationships for drag on a sphere.

Comment: In addition to what Chester Miller said, you might also want to correct for the effect of finite size of the well on droplet's motion.